# Why do brackets mess up this math in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

Why do the two calculations have differing results? This is xcode 6.1.

```
(lldb) print newBounds.size.height
(CGFloat) $0 = 446.5
(lldb) print newBounds.size.height * 6/4
(double) $1 = 669.75
(lldb) print newBounds.size.height * (6/4)
(double) $2 = 446.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just integer math and the usual rules for promotion of types.

```
height * 6/4 == (height * (double)6) / (double)4 == (height * 6.0) / 4.0
```

whereas:

```
height * (6/4) == height * (double)(1) == height * 1.0
```

since `6/4 == 1` and the parentheses force this to be evaluated first before promoting it to `double`.

This is the same behaviour as in C, C++, Objective-C, *et al*, so you shouldn't be too surprised to see it in your debugger too.

Comment: I just hadn't come across promotion of types before.